# Styling Anchor Text (a name)

Tags: css, anchor

I have these anchors:

```
<h2><a name="facebook">facebook</a></h2>
<h2><a name="mobilephone">mobilephone</a></h2>
```

At the moment the text is blue because it is a link. I'm trying to change the color so they are the same as all other H2 text.

I've tried:

```
.name {
        color:red !important;
    }

:name {
        color:red !important;
    }

:facebook {
    color:red !important;
}

a:name {
    color:red !important;
}

a:facebook {
    color:red !important;
}

a[name=facebook]{
    color:red !important;
}

a[name]{
    color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: can you try  `h2 a{ color: red !important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you are looking for css property text-decoration 
Here you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration):

My solution for your problem is :

```
h2 a {
    color:red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Look at Demo :https://jsfiddle.net/wre1yLvn/

Comment: No, the OP is specifically looking to change the color. They ever mentioned `text-decoration`: *I'm trying to change the color so they are the same as all other H2 text.*

Answer (score 2):

Attribute selectors in CSS should work in this instance, but since you're setting the colour of all `h2 a` elements, why do you need the attribute selector? Wouldn't this be sufficient:

```
h2 a {
    color: red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xe7p8us8/1/)

If you must use the attribute selector for `name`, use:

```
a[name="facebook"],
a[name="mobilephone"] {
    color: red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xe7p8us8/)

To read more about attribute selectors in CSS, refer to the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style all anchors which just have a `name` but not links, you can go with something like:

```css
a[name]:not(:link) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a name="header">Header</a>
<a href="http://gurustop.net">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use exactly the same color as the `h2` you should use this

```
h2 {
 color: red;
}

h2 > a {
 color: inherit;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/aLncaegh/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
h2 a:visited {
color: inherit;
}
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp